# Block user input without affecting the movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this piece of movement script to move my character around:

```
Vector3 vector = Vector3.zero;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
{
   vector += Vector3.forward;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
   vector += Vector3.back;
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
   vector += Vector3.left;
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
   vector += Vector3.right;
}

if (grounded) 
{
   transform.Translate(vector.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I also have a collision detection code that affects boolean `grounded`. I use it to detect when the player's jumping.
I wanted to do so when the character isn't on the ground player couldn't move it BUT the character still moves in the direction before the jump. Right now if I jump the character stops midair.
I guess I could use my RidgidBody, but I don't think this is the right choice.
Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are expecting your character to keep moving such as he was running forwards and now jumps, using the rigidbody movement would seem very logical. All that you dont want is you dont want user input to change the direction he was originally heading in or to be able to jump again

Comment: Why do you think the `Rigidbody` wouldn't be right?

Comment: @BugFinder I could use RidgidBody.MovePossition(), but still how do I make it so I don't let the player move the character midair? (I kinda new to this stuff)

Comment: using the rigidbody you give it momentum, or velocity, it handles it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `transform.Translate(vector.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` is what makes your character actually move. Since you've put under a `if (grounded)` this means the character will stop moving altogether if grounded is false (as long as you don't have anything else making it move).

Instead, what you want to do is to preserve the state `vector` was in when you jumped so that your character will keep moving in the same direction. You can do so by putting the entire input block under the `if (grounded)` condition and having vector as a global variable rather than a local one. Here what it would look like:

Declare `vector` in the class rather than in function.

```
Vector3 vector;
```

Then the actual logic code:

```
if (grounded) 
{
  vector = Vector3.zero;

  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
  {
     vector += Vector3.forward;
  }
  else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
  {
     vector += Vector3.back;
  }

  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
  {
     vector += Vector3.left;
  }
  else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
  {
     vector += Vector3.right;
  }
}

transform.Translate(vector.normalized * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```